# When am I try to reuse PNPM store, I getting 'cross-device link not permitted' in Docker build on GitLab CI

Tags: node.js, docker, gitlab, cicd, pnpm

I'm trying to reuse pnpm store with docker buildkit inline cache. It is working fine, when I'm doing local build but on gitlab ci it throw `cross-device link not permitted` error.

Error

```
...
#12 2.257  WARN  EXDEV: cross-device link not permitted, link '/root/.local/share/pnpm/store/v3/files/68/31d9850g49ag49cc526af456f4a19a0f76eb85a79b6b311f09df7dd62a2a4d0f5c83de4eb5c6648f8bff155c82edce40a4e6c61cvb71127e1cb93c3cb8ab0f' -> '/usr/app/node_modules/.pnpm/on-exit-leak-free@0.2.0/node_modules/_tmp_1_58b64396e8cfdcdv7a5b403e046a9203/LICENSE'
#12 2.257 Falling back to copying packages from store
#12 2.316  WARN  EXDEV: cross-device link not permitted, link '/root/.local/share/pnpm/store/v3/files/6b/416bd4d9c57a078ff0a54c56f32039bb01aa5b3a3f07bev60d8ecc6eaa830db5ac4192943d693baaa1fc09b7891306db00055f3805ee6cc02ff353d8477f5c' -> '/usr/app/node_modules/.pnpm/pino-abstract-transport@0.5.0/node_modules/_tmp_1_ae5f485297e737f5f3943671v7fd357d/.github/dependabot.yml'
#12 2.316 Falling back to copying packages from store
#12 2.741  WARN  EXDEV: cross-device link not permitted, link '/root/.local/share/pnpm/store/v3/files/ba/80df1a5d3176e962200ca4d1304c02617df7ba747736cada94d29e94883f71f4b3231ee0a02c33886ba454215f65ff4320e0cc49f22fb431383f88c483cb9e' -> '/usr/app/node_modules/.pnpm/stack-chain@1.3.7/node_modules/_tmp_1_c0e9a25e81dg99592va167a1v86c382s/package.json'
#12 2.741 Falling back to copying packages from store
#12 3.174 Progress: resolved 624, reused 0, downloaded 101, added 96
#12 4.175 Progress: resolved 624, reused 0, downloaded 184, added 179
#12 5.175 Progress: resolved 624, reused 0, downloaded 229, added 220
...
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package.json .babelrc jsconfig.json esbuild.config.js pnpm-lock.yaml ./
COPY src ./src

RUN npm install -g pnpm

RUN --mount=type=cache,id=pnpm,target=/root/.local/share/pnpm/store \
    pnpm fetch

RUN pnpm install --recursive --offline --frozen-lockfile --prod --unsafe-perm && \
    pnpm run build

FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package.json esbuild.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /usr/app/dist dist

EXPOSE 3030

CMD node dist/bundle.js
```

GitLab CI

```yaml
build:
  image: docker:stable
  services:
    - docker:dind
  stage: build
  script:
  - export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
  - docker build --cache-from $CONTAINER_IMAGE -t $CONTAINER_IMAGE --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 .
```

Comment: I am getting this warning even on my local Mac M1, but even with this warning packages are getting reused. And only newly added packages are getting downloaded. #16 1.245  WARN  EXDEV: cross-device link not permitted, link '/pnpm/store/v3/files/29/844c3773154ee8b2e579050c77793e74261da427b77cf5ea7b010de3f167d60d9aaec8165b25a41065477508fb3be56c47a6ce8c0e61e2a297d6b4664398c5' -> '/app/node_modules/.pnp...
#16 10.53 Progress: resolved 341, reused 340, downloaded 1, added 341
#16 10.66 
#16 11.53 Progress: resolved 341, reused 340, downloaded 1, added 341, done
#16 DONE 11.9s

Comment: Do you have the same behavior on Gitlab CI?

Comment: Is you gitlab ci configured, so that each run gets started on the same host and that you are allowed to use caching on host machine?

Comment: No, acutely 0 reuse. In gitlab ci, they spin up new container for each build.

Comment: I have the exact same issue but using Github actions, where you ever able to overcome it?